# Check every hour if specific html classes exists on external websites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to check a few external links every few hours for some specific classes. 
For example, I have this 2 links:

```
https://nike.com/product-1/
https://adidas.com/product1/
```

On each one of these links, I want to check every few hours if a specific class exists. More exactly, I want to check the stock availability for each one of those sizes(S, M, L, XL...).

If any size from those two links is "out of stock" I want to receive an email with a message.

From my research, I found that I can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML.

This is what I have started:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://nike.com/product-1/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

stock = []
for h2_tag in soup.find_all('h2'):
a_tag = h2_tag.find('a')

print(urls)
```

This seems pretty complicated and it's just a start... I have the impression that there might be simpler ways of doing this.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Check their network activity to see if any populate the page with an api call.

Comment: As suggested, you can check and see if you can get a nice json response from an API. If not, then might need to use Selenium, as I'm assuming these pages will be dynamic and rendered after the intial page request. Can you provide 2 specific links instead of the 2 generic example links (as those two links don't actually return anything) so I can play around and take a look?

Comment: @chitown88 I'm afraid I cannot use API's because there are no API's. Here are two specific links: https://www.zara.com/ro/ro/tricou-cu-imprimeu-contrastant-p04873406.html?v1=13238097&v2=1181082  https://www2.hm.com/ro_ro/productpage.0598755002.html

Comment: @agis, if that's the case, then ya, you'll most likely need to use sometype of automated browser. I'll take a lok now and see what I can come up with it.

Comment: @agis, the tricky part is you'll be checking on different sites, and each site will have a different layout/structure. So checking for a specific class could be tough as each site may have a different string for it's classes representing the sizes. So you may need to create a different function for each base site.

Comment: I'd take a better look, because at least for the zara site, they use json responses for the [recommended](https://pro.api-mirror.wide-eyes.it/zara/v2/RecommendById?ajax=true)